# Using a selector as a parameter?

Tags: jquery, parameters, jquery-selectors

So, this is the working function that I want to use for all of my buttons, but I ofcourse don't want to have to write it 5 times in a row.

```
$(".concept-button").click(function() {
$('html,body').animate({
    scrollTop: $(".concept-section").offset().top},'slow');
});
```

So, what am I doing wrong below?

```
var scrollFunction = function(sectionToScrollTo) {
    $('html,body').animate({
    scrollTop: ( sectionToScrollTo).offset().top},'slow' );
};

 $(".strategy-button").click( scrollFunction( $(".strategy-section") ) );
```

Answer (score 2):

The problem is you are invoking the function `scrollFunction`() instead of registering it as a click callback. In your case you are calling `scrollFunction` with the said parameters and then is passing the value returned from it(`undefined`) to the click handler, which means no click handler is registered.

Instead what you can do is to make `scrollFunction` to return the callback function which will be passed to `click()` as the callback.

```
var scrollFunction = function (sectionToScrollTo) {
    return function () {
        $('html,body').animate({
            scrollTop: sectionToScrollTo.offset().top
        }, 'slow');
    }
};
$(".strategy-button").click(scrollFunction($(".strategy-section")));
```